# @RequestMapping does not redirect me to my url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am entering Spring MVC but it does not redirect me to the url with the RequestMappin, it only does it with the main page but with the others if I add it manual it does not execute, what can I have wrong?

the url that I use to enter login is http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc/login

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login.do")   <------------------This work
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private LoginService service = new LoginService();


@Controller
public class LoginController {  <!---------------------------This not-->

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public String decirHola() {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }
```

````
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
        `<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>`
       ` <servlet-class>`
           ` org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  ```  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring-mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
````

```
<!--                        pom                   -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>`
```

Comment: There is too little information to begin answering this question.

Comment: practically that is what I have in mind, since the rest are methods, but my question is why it calls me to one url and not the other, therefore, I put the pom.xml, and the web.xml to see if I have Some error about it because I can not find and the program does not tell me that I have an error, only tomcat tells me that the address could not be found, Because what other information would be required to learn more about the problem and thus be able to find what I need?